# How do I find intersection of mouse click and a 3D mesh?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

In my program I'm loading in a 3D mesh to view and interact with. The user can rotate and scale the view. I will be using a rotation matrix for the rotation and calling `multmatrix` to rotate the view, and scaling using `glScalef`. The user can also paint the mesh, and this is why I need to translate the mouse coordinates to see if it intersects with the mesh.

I've read http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm and the method where I use gluUnproject at the near and far plane and subtracting, and I have some success with it, but only when gluLookAt's position is (0, 0, z) where z can be any reasonable number. When I move the position to say (0, 1, z), it goes haywire and returns an intersection where there is only empty space, and returns no intersection where the mesh is clearly underneath the mouse.

This is how I'm making the ray from the mouse click to the scene:

```
float hx, hy;
hx = mouse_x;
hy = mouse_y;

GLdouble m1x,m1y,m1z,m2x,m2y,m2z;
GLint viewport[4];
GLdouble projMatrix[16], mvMatrix[16];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,viewport);
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mvMatrix);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,projMatrix);

//unproject to find actual coordinates
gluUnProject(hx,scrHeight-hy,2.0,mvMatrix,projMatrix,viewport,&m1x,&m1y,&m1z);
gluUnProject(hx,scrHeight-hy,10.0,mvMatrix,projMatrix,viewport,&m2x,&m2y,&m2z);

gmVector3 dir = gmVector3(m2x,m2y,m2z) - gmVector3(m1x,m1y,m1z);
dir.normalize();

gmVector3 point;
bool intersected = findIntersection(gmVector3(0,0,5), dir, point);
```

I'm using glFrustum if that makes any difference.

The findIntersection code is really long and I'm pretty confident it works, so I won't post it unless someone wants to see it. The gist of it is that for every face in the mesh, find intersection between the ray and the plane, then see if the intersection point is inside the face.

I believe that it has to do with the camera's position and look at vector, but I don't know how, and what to do with them so that the mouse clicks on the mesh properly. Can anyone help me with this?

I also haven't yet made the rotation matrix or anything with the `glScalef`, so can anyone give me insight into this? Like, does unproject account for the `multmatrix` and `glScalef` calls when calculating?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you call `glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mvMatrix)` before or after `gluLookAt()`?

Comment: gluLookAt is inside the draw function itself, and the function outlined above is called when a user clicks the mouse inside the window. So, gluLookAt gets called first, I believe.

Comment: Is the camera positioned at (0,0,5)?

Comment: Yes. It's only for testing right now, I'll use variables later. I made sure to change this when I try using other numbers in gluLookAt so the numbers are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making the ray from the camera to the scene using the ray `dir`, I should've used:

```
bool intersected = findIntersection(gmVector3(m1x,m1y,m1z), dir, point);
```

(notice the different vector being passed to the function). This solved my problem, and didn't have anything to do with the gluLookAt after all!

Also, for the second part of the question that I asked, yes, the unproject does take into account the glScale and glmultmatrix functions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is with raytracing. The ray you shoot is defined through two points. The first one is the origin of the camera, the second one is the mouse position projected on the view plane in the scene (the plane you describe with glFrustum). The intersection of this ray with you model is the point where your mouse click has hit the model

Comment: I find that the camera's lookAt matters as well, since when I move the camera position (and not the lookAt), the ball is drawn in the middle of the screen, but the intersections happen off to the side.